# How to get attachment URL programmatically From SharePoint list item?

Tags: splistitem, visual-web-part, splist

How to get **attachment full URL** programmatically From SharePoint list item?

Explanation:

I have adding new item with attachment.
Now I have to bind that attachment link to grid.
When click on that link Attachment should be open.

How can I get Attachment URL of that item?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found answer for my question.

```
private string GetAttachmentUrls(SPListItem oItem)
{

        string path = string.Empty;

        try

        {

            path = (from string file in oItem.Attachments
                              orderby file
                              select SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(oItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix, file)).FirstOrDefault();
            return path;
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you please give a bit explanation of this code?

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way:

```
    private string GetAttachmentURL(SPAttachmentCollection attchmentcollection) {
        string URL="#";
        foreach (var item in attchmentcollection)
        {
            URL = attchmentcollection.UrlPrefix + item;
            break;
        }

        return URL;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using below code:

```
string attachmentURL = splistitem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + splistitem.Attachments[0];
```

Regards,

Nabeel