# How take url Attachments for all items in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, splistitem, splist

I have an `SPList`. How I can get attachment URLs for every item in the list?

Comment: Here is similar question on [stackexchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54668/how-to-get-attachment-url-programatically-from-sharepoint-listitem) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that bit of code might be slow depending on the size of the list:

```
foreach (SPListItem listItem in list.Items)
{
    var attachmentURLs = GetAttachmentUrls(listItem)
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetAttachmentUrls(SPListItem item)
{
  return from string fileName in item.Attachments
         orderby fileName
         select SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(item.Attachments.UrlPrefix, fileName);
}
```

Credit to this post: [How do I get the url for attachments on an SPListItem using C#?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32077/how-do-i-get-the-url-for-attachments-on-an-splistitem-using-c) I just added a `foreach` loop.

Comment: The question is tagged SharePoint Online, if that is the truth this code will not work

Comment: Just noticed that, let's see if the user confirms it. Thanks.

Comment: I do in `foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)` like u say with `SPListItem`, but I see `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator\`2[System.String,System.String] ` when out this.

Comment: If you marked it as an answer, I assume this was SharePoint Server and not Office 365?

Answer (score 1):

You can get list item attachments using REST api as in below code:

```
var url = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    accepts: {
        json: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    method: "GET",
    success: onQuerySuccess,
    error: onQueryError
});

function onQuerySuccess(data) {
    if (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function () {
            // do something
            this.ServerRelativeUrl;
        });
    }
}
```

Here "items(1)" is the id of the list item

Comment: I must do it task without js, but thanks for asnwer.