# Try get attachments to SPList

Tags: splistitem, attachments, splist, ssom

I tried using [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54668/how-to-get-attachment-url-programatically-from-sharepoint-listitem) solution with the following code:

```
 using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
        SPList list = web.Lists[ListName];
        items = list.GetItems();
        table = items.GetDataTable();

        DataColumn urlAttachs = table.Columns.Add("AttachUrl", typeof(String));
        string t;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
          foreach (SPListItem listItem in list.Items)
          {
             t = GetAttachmentUrls(listItem).ToString();
             row["AttachUrl"] = t;
          }
        }
   }
```

But as a result I got only one attachment, which was added last.
How can I get the full list of attachments for every item in the list? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Once you intance the item, **loop** within **attachments collection**.

Sample code:

```
SPAttachmentCollection attachments = listItem.Attachments;
foreach (string attachment in attachments)
{
  string t = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(listItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix, attachment );
}
```

Source: [SurPoint](http://surpoint.blogspot.com.ar/2016/03/como-listar-los-adjuntos-de-un-item-de.html)